# If $A$ is an invertible matrix of order 2, then $|A^*|$ is (where $A^*$ is inverse of matrix $A$)

Tags: determinant

I am having some formula *without proof* (u can find it by ur self) $\def\adj{\operatorname{adj}}$

$A^* = 1/|A| \cdot \adj A $

and

$|\adj A| = |A|^{n-1}$ where $n$ is order of matrix

By using these formulae

$$\begin{align}
|A^*| &= 1/|A| \cdot |\adj A|\qquad \text  {as $|A|$ is constant}\\ 
&= 1/|A| \cdot |A|^{n-1}\\
&= |A|^{n-2}
\end{align}
$$
Now here $n$ is 2 
So finally we gotta

$|A^*| = |A|^0 = 1$
But why it is not 1. Plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

Note when $M$ has order $n$, we have $|kM| = k^n \cdot|M|$, not $k\cdot|M|.$  Therefore, 
$$|A^*| = 1/|A|^n \cdot |\text{adj } A| = |A|^{-1}$$

---

For future reference: OP has used $A^*$ for the inverse of $A$ so I have used this notation.  This should not be confused with the common notation of the conjugate transpose.

Comment: @5Dots You have written  $$\text{|A*| = 1/|A| × |adj A| (as |A| is constant)}$$ My whole point is that this is wrong unless $n=1$.  Therefore, when you ask the only question: "But why it is not 1...... " it's because you misapplied the determinant.

Comment: @5Dots As best I can tell, you're mixing up two formulas.  The following both are true: $$\text{inv}(A) = 1/|A| \cdot \text{adj}(A) \\ |\text{inv}(A)| = 1/|A|^n \cdot |\text{adj}(A)|$$

Comment: Ok thanks i got this, sorry for the trouble man. Appreciates a lot